# Ruby Block syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax, boolean, block

I was going through some code I found online and found the following

```
def change input 
   ('a'..'z').map { |letter| input.downcase.include?(letter) ? '1' : '0' }.join
end
```

I understand what this code is doing. It will take a string, check if the string contains each letter of the alphabet and return 1 if true and 0 if false.

However I am unfamiliar with this bit of syntax:

```
?(letter) ? '1' : '0' }
```

I know that a question mark is usually used to indicate that the method will return a boolean result. But I am insure why there is a second question mark after the argument.

Also, I understand that this will return 1 if true and 0 if false. Is that what this colon represents. Is it always ok to use a colon like this if the result of the method in the block will be a boolean?

Comment: `condition ? do_this_if_true : do_this_if_false`

Comment: This will actually create a string of 1's and 0's, not just a 1 or 0 - just to be clear

Answer (score 1):

The format `boolean_expression ? option_a : option_b` is called a ternary operator. It is short for

```
if boolean_expression
  option_a
else
  option_b
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The first question mark is part of the [#include? method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F)

The expession `condition ? if_true : if_false` is called a ternary operator, which is shorthand for

```
if condition
  if_true
else
  if_false
end
```